# Дергается прокрутка

Tags: html, css

Имеется сайт: https://worket.ml/
Сверстал главную страницу, и понял, что скроллинг почему-то дергается. Уже до невозможного сжал картинки, но ничего не изменилось. В чем причина? Буду благодарен любому совету. Сразу скажу, что flat-ui.min.js отключать пробовал, практически никакого эффекта это не дало. 
Скорее всего, дело в main.css, в нем - https://worket.ml/css/main.css
Но в чем конкретно - понять не могу, пробовал удалять все эффекты картинок - толку не дало.

Comment: Оформите вопрос соответствующим образом, с добавлением кода. См. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2653/%d0%9e%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83

Comment: Дело в том, что я и сам понятия не имею, в чем проблема. Одно знаю наверняка - дело в main.css, в нем - https://worket.ml/css/main.css
Но в чем конкретно - понять не могу, пробовал удалять все эффекты картинок - толку не дало.

Comment: Скорее всего, перенагрузка на хостинг

Comment: @Niklex Не думаю, т.к. это виртуальный сервер, [скрин](http://i004.radikal.ru/1603/48/6dc30110e34d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите блюр с `img.blur`

А еще уберите фиксированное позиционирование с `.bg-img`

И думайте как по другому зафиксировать фоновую картинку.